# How i can login user from facebook , twitter and linkden in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi i want to login user from facebook ,twitter and linkden like many other sites in my rails

application.Which gem is suitable for this or devise amniouth can do all this.Any guidelines

,blogs ,or books you will refer.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, omniauth would be the best way to do this. This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast) explains everything very clearly,